# Error inflating class suddenly

Tags: android

I am getting error suddenly and can't find out solution. It was working proper but I don't know why it is started to show error.

`activity_main.xml` code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
  tools:context="com.soft32.messaging.MainActivity"
>

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:id="@+id/laymain">
<include
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar" />


<it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
       android:id="@+id/materialTabHost"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
       app:accentColor="@color/colorAccent"
       app:primaryColor="@color/colorPrimary"
       />

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/viewPager"
   android:layout_below="@+id/laymain">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>




</RelativeLayout>
```

error is below:

I'm getting the following error: `Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soft32.messaging/com.soft32.messaging.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:627)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
at com.soft32.messaging.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:601)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
at com.soft32.messaging.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: it.neokree.materialtabs.R$styleable
at it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost.<init>(MaterialTabHost.java:71)
at it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost.<init>(MaterialTabHost.java:57)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:601) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:703) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:762) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:771) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136) 
at com.soft32.messaging.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:88) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5447) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your actual error is `NoClassDefFoundError: it.neokree.materialtabs.R$styleable`

Comment: Where does `it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost` come from? Is that a dependency you have downloaded?

Comment: If it is [this library](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialTabs), you may want to read the README that says it is no longer supported. You should use `TabLayout` from the support library instead.

Comment: I think you can't nest it in another layout, it has to be at the first level